# Kinetic Blast with multiple saves

Tags: pathfinder-1e, kineticist

[Kineticist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/)'s [Kinetic Blast](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Kineticist/#TOC-Kinetic-Blast-Sp-) can be modified with 1 form [infusion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Kineticist/#TOC-Infusion-Su-) and 1 substance infusion.  Some of these form infusions change the blast from an attack roll to a reflex save.  Some of the substance  infusions have a fortitude/will save.

If I were to say do a [Thundering Torrent Electric Blast](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/infusion-wild-talents/), would that incur a reflex save to half, or a fort save to negate the deafen?  Or would you only roll the fort save on a failed reflex save?

How do multiple saves interact in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your confusion comes from the thundering infusion. The fort save isn't about the damage, it's for the deafened condition that has been applied to the blast.

From [Infusion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Kineticist/#TOC-Infusion-Su-) the order is blast, form, substance for you since both do not alter the blast damage.

> When a kineticist modifies a kinetic blast with a form infusion and a substance infusion that both require saving throws, each target first attempts a saving throw against the form infusion. [removed irrelevant line] If a kineticist’s form and substance infusions both alter the kinetic blast’s damage, apply the substance infusion’s alteration first.

The blast attack roll (which is electric damage due to the electric blast) is replaced by the form infusion which is Torrent which becomes a reflex save. The Thundering infusion does not change the damage, so its save is added on second.

For people with evasion or improved evasion, if they are successful on the reflex save against the torrent infusion, then they take no damage and are not required to make the fort save due to the removed line from above, as was pointed out by Ifusaso.

> If a target succeeds and a successful save negates the infusion’s effects, the entire kinetic blast is negated; otherwise, the target then attempts a saving throw against the substance infusion.

Comment: While that's probably a good houserule on how to apply Evasion, that is not actually what Evasion says/does by the book. "If she makes a successful Reflex saving throw against an attack that normally deals half damage on a successful save, she instead **takes no damage.**"

Comment: That also isn't particularly relevant to the question, imo

Comment: @Ifusaso I included it so that the entire consideration was covered, and to prevent a potential future question. Yes it was more than asked, but I felt it important to include.

Comment: Oh I see. You were referencing the rules from Infusion without quoting them (I forgot it was an exception to how Reflex Saves are normally handled with Evasion) "If a target succeeds and a successful save negates the infusion’s effects, the entire kinetic blast is negated; otherwise, the target then attempts a saving throw against the substance infusion." Should probably be referenced before mentioning Evasion

Comment: @Ifusaso Um, yes, I totally intentionally referenced that rule. I was going with how regular magic works with evasion, glad to know it holds true for this as well.